# Mouse Events in Jasmine

Tags: jquery, jasmine

I'm new to Jasmine and jQuery and am having trouble spying on a mousedown event. Here's the part of my spec that's failing (Jasmine says that that the spy mousedown hasn't been called.) I suspect that it may be because of the way that I trigger the event.

```
it("draws a path on mousedown", function() {
  spyOn(drawing,'mousedown');
  $('#canvas').trigger('mousedown');
  expect(drawing.mousedown).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(drawing.isDrawing).toEqual(true);
});
```

The corresponding Javascript code is here:

```
function Drawing(canvas, eraseAllButton, eraseButton) {
  this.isDrawing = false;
  this.erasing = false;
  this.canvas = canvas;
  this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.eraseAllButton = eraseAllButton;
  this.eraseButton = eraseButton;

// Sets up event listeners for drawing.
  var self = this;
  this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function () { self.mousedown() }, false);
};

// Begins to draw a path on mousedown.
Drawing.prototype.mousedown = function(e) { 
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  e.preventDefault();       

  this.isDrawing = true;
  this.x = e.pageX - this.canvas.offsetLeft;
  this.y = e.pageY - this.canvas.offsetTop;
  this.context.beginPath();
  this.context.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
};
```

Comment: Is the full spec available somewhere so we can see your beforeEach etc? Perhaps create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var mouse = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
mouse.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
$('#canvas').get(0).dispatchEvent(mouse);
```

Comment: how do we do this in jquery?